# Getting error when parsing JSON in Swift 3

Tags: json, swift, xcode, swift3

**1. This is the response String**

```
{"error_msg": null,"applicationStateJson": {"notifications_size": "0","dfilterlogin": 1,"loginstype": null,"email_status": "0","address_status": "0","defaultfiltername": "hyderabad","login_status": "1","defaultfilterid": 145,"profile_id": null,"freelancer": "Y","otp_status": "1","notifications": []},"status": null}
```

**2. Below one is the perfect JSONObject, I get it to using JSONLint**

```
{
"error_msg": null,
"applicationStateJson": {
    "notifications_size": "0",
    "dfilterlogin": 1,
    "loginstype": null,
    "email_status": "0",
    "address_status": "0",
    "defaultfiltername": "hyderabad",
    "login_status": "1",
    "defaultfilterid": 145,
    "profile_id": null,
    "freelancer": "Y",
    "otp_status": "1",
    "notifications": []
},
"status": null
}
```

**3. When I try the below code in Swift 3**

```
let json1 = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])

                    if let object = json1 as? [String: Any]{

                        if let applicationState = object["applicationStateJson"] as? [String: Any]{
                            print("applicationState   \(applicationState)")
                        }
                    }
```

**4. I got JSONObject but it's not a proper JSONObject**

***(because the commas are changed into semicolon, null values are changed into "< null >" and then empty array [] changed into ())***

```
Optional({
applicationStateJson =     {
    "address_status" = 0;
    defaultfilterid = 145;
    defaultfiltername = hyderabad;
    dfilterlogin = 1;
    "email_status" = 0;
    freelancer = Y;
    "login_status" = 1;
    loginstype = "<null>";
    notifications =         (
    );
    "notifications_size" = 0;
    "otp_status" = 1;
    "profile_id" = "<null>";
};
"error_msg" = "<null>";
status = "<null>";
})
```

**I want the JSONObject like the step 2, any help?**

Comment: it *is* the same, its just been converted from a JSON string to a Swift Dictionary object

Comment: how can I change it again JSON string?

Comment: Finally, i found the way, {if let theJSONData = try?  JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: applicationState, options: .prettyPrinted),
let theJSONText = String(data: theJSONData, encoding: String.Encoding.ascii) {
                                    print("JSON string = \n\(theJSONText)")
                                }}

Comment: can i ask why you want to convert JSON string to Swift object and then partially create JSON string again?. it sounds like you are doing stuff you don't need to do

Comment: why because I want to parse JSON object from the JSON object that is I want applicationStateJson from the response

Comment: There are much easier/better ways to read JSON data in Swift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read and use a JSON response in Swift does not require you to convert the JSON object back to JSON just to get a particular part. Once you have the data loaded into a Swift type you can work directly with it to get the parts you need.

**So the long way which explains my point better...**

```
let jsonData = jsonString.data(using: .utf8)!
let json1 = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: [])

if let object = json1 as? [String: Any]{

    if let applicationState = object["applicationStateJson"] as? [String: Any]{
        print("applicationState   \(applicationState)")

        if let addressStatus = applicationState["address_status"] as? String {
            print(addressStatus)
        }
    }
}
```

**The Swift 4 way of doing this with the Codable Protocol**

```
let jsonString = "{\"error_msg\": null,\"applicationStateJson\": {\"notifications_size\": \"0\",\"dfilterlogin\": 1,\"loginstype\": null,\"email_status\": \"0\",\"address_status\": \"0\",\"defaultfiltername\": \"hyderabad\",\"login_status\": \"1\",\"defaultfilterid\": 145,\"profile_id\": null,\"freelancer\": \"Y\",\"otp_status\": \"1\",\"notifications\": []},\"status\": null}"

struct ApplicationState: Codable {
    let notificationsSize: String
    let dFilterLogin: Int
    let loginsType: String?
    let emailStatus: String
    let addressStatus: String

    enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case notificationsSize = "notifications_size"
        case dFilterLogin = "dfilterlogin"
        case addressStatus = "address_status"
        case loginsType = "loginstype"
        case emailStatus = "email_status"
    }
}

struct ApplicationStateResponse: Codable {
    let errorMsg: String?
    let applicationState: ApplicationState

    enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case errorMsg = "error_msg"
        case applicationState = "applicationStateJson"
    }
}

let jsonData = jsonString.data(using: .utf8)!
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let response = try! decoder.decode(ApplicationStateResponse.self, from: jsonData)
let appState = response.applicationState

print(appState.addressStatus)
```

Both of these print 0 for the address status as expected. one is much easier to work with than the other though.

This [article](https://benscheirman.com/2017/06/swift-json/) which explains the codable protocol a bit more would be a good read.

Answer (score 0):

Convert Swift Dictionary object to JSON string,

```
if let theJSONData = try?  JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: applicationState, options: .prettyPrinted),
                                let theJSONText = String(data: theJSONData, encoding: String.Encoding.ascii) {
                                print("JSON string = \n\(theJSONText)")
                            }
```

Comment: how can I get applicationStateJson form jsonString, using your code?

Comment: You didn't mention in the question that you want only a part of the JSON string.